# Contact form: not receiving e-mail

Tags: php, forms, contact-form

I am making my record label's official website and just arrived to the contact page of it.
I had tried to set it up in a different way, asking help by Google with no positive result!
Here you can see my actual using contact form's php part:

```
<?php
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $from = 'From: my website name'; 
    $to = 'my@email.com'; 
    $subject = 'New message from the Website!';

    $body = "From: $name\n Subject:\n $subject E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message ";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
            if ($human == '4') {                 
               if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                   echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
                } else { 
                    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
                } 
            } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
                echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
        }
    }

    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: contact.html');
?>
```

Here is the HTML form:

```
<form role="form"  action="send.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">name</label>
              <input type="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name *">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email *">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="subject">Subject</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" id="subject">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="message">message</label>
              <textarea id="message" cols="30" rows="7" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
              <label for="text" >*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
              <input name="human" placeholder="2 + 2 =">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn-default">Send it</button>
          </form>
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: Is this on a local server? Or a live website server? Have you checked the spam filters? Have you tested multiple email addresses? What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: If you're just typing in the name in the from field, put in an email address instead and see if it bounces with some info.

Comment: May I ask what's the output after you submit the form?

Comment: Tested on live website. There is no any emails in the inbox or spam box.

After the submit it gets back to the same contact page!

Comment: You forgot to add `$human=$_REQUEST['human'];` @Roland which is most likely the reason it's not working.

Comment: added, and still nothing!

Comment: Then try changing this `<button type="submit" class="btn-default">Send it</button>` to `<input type="submit" class="btn-default" value="Send it">` @Roland

Comment: Actually, made a mistake. `<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-default" value="Send it">` @Roland

Comment: You need to fix your conditional statements then.

Comment: so you advice to create a whole new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for `$_POST['submit']` which is never set, because no input field or button of your form is named "submit".

Change your button to:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn-default" name="submit" value="Send it">
```

or set a hidden field named submit:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="value">
```

And then your redirect will fail with the "Header already sent" error, because you must not have output before a `header()` call.
Put the `header()` call in an `else` part of your `if($_POST['submit'])`

The same is for every other input field. The name is missing. Instead you use the name as the type. The type should be "text" everywhere.

Comment: Can you (just for debugging) remove the header call and replace it with an echo which outputs something? Then we can see, what the script does.

Comment: can you please help a bit more pls, i an a newcomer in programming
So i will delete the header call and put instead of it:
echo 'what i need to put here'

Comment: It doesn't matter. Just type `echo "test";` to see, if "test" is displayed.

Comment: got back this:
"You need to fill in all required fields!!

test"

But i had filled everything in! :O

Comment: Ah okay..that's the same error - you must name your input fields with name="thename" - for example name="name" or name="email". And the type should be "text" everywhere.

Comment: nice! Thank you so much Marcel! it worked!
and thanks for everybody who tried to help me!

Answer (score -1):

first try with plain function with hard coded  parameters to mail() function, make sure you are receiving it.

example :

```
mail('your@email.com', 'hi', 'hello', 'from@email.com');
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be a comment?

Comment: check the similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803994/php-mail-not-working-for-some-reason