# PHP not sending email

Tags: php, email

Iam new to php coding. I have tried to send an email from an html page.It is redirected to my 'email.php', but it doesn,t send email.My code is here..

```
<?php

//if "email" is filled out, send email

  //send email
  $name = $_REQUEST['your-name'] ;
   $email = $_REQUEST['your-email'] ;
   $company= $_REQUEST['company'] ;
    $website= $_REQUEST['website'] ;
  $message=$name."<br>".$company."<br>".$website."<br>".$email;
  $subject = 'Hai there' ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
  mail("sample@gmail.com", $subject,
  $message, "From:" . $email);
  if(mail()){
  echo 'successfull';
  }
  else{
   echo 'not successfull';
  }


?>
```

It always shows 'not successful'.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
if(mail()){
```

with

```
if(mail("sample@gmail.com", $subject,  $message, "From:" . $email)){
```

Comment: @Ansar, The you are doing your `mail()` wrong. See the basic example here on PHP Manual. http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-examples

Comment: I have checked it but it couldn't send emails

Comment: Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your PHP script and see what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to check your php.ini config, have a look to this comment:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8804035/2910910

And this comment:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php#77499

Good luck!

Comment: i have tried it in the real server.Then how can i fix this poblem.?