# Why is `mail()` in php not working with `LAMP(Linux Apache Mysql PHP`?

Tags: php, lamp

I am working on a `contact us` form, which sends an email to an email ID.

Following is the php script :

```
<?php
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];

        $email_from = "xxx@yyy.co.in";
        $email_subject = "New form submission";
        $email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name";

        $to = "xxx@yyy.co.in";
        $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

        $flag = mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
        echo $flag;
    ?>
```

When I click `Submit` button I send a `POST` call to the page containing above script.

I receive form data correctly on that php page, but the email is not sent to the concerned email ID. The php `mail()` function returns `false`.

What may be the problem? Do I need to configure anything in the `php.ini` file?

I am working on Linux Mint and using LAMP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803994/php-mail-not-working-for-some-reason

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail not working for some reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803994/php-mail-not-working-for-some-reason)