# PHP mail sending is not working

Tags: php, email, html-email

I am trying to send an email using following php script.it gives me "mail sent" status but it actually does not sends mails to gmail and yahoo accounts.

```
<?php

$to      = "xxxxx@yahoo.com";

$subject = 'subject'; // Give the email a subject
$message = '

        Thanks for signing up!
        Your account has been created. ';


$headers .= 'From:noreply@ccs.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc:xxxxx@gmail.com' ."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc:yyyyy@gmail.com' ."\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo "mail sent";

?>
```

Comment: remove dot from  $headers .= 'From:noreply@ccs.com' . "\r\n";

Comment: Did you verified in the mail  whether you have received it or not.. If not in inbox, then check it out in spam folder..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail not working for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8803994/6521116)

Comment: @ManiRaj yes i checked it doesn't exist in spam folder also

Comment: is this running on your localhost?