# PHP mail() function not working despite confirmation

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

I have created a form that allows people to send an email from a website. The HTML code (see attached) calls a PHP script (see attached), and the email is supposed to be sent. The webpage displays the message "Email successfully sent", but I never actually received the email (it's not in spam either).

I have reached out to my hosting service (awaiting reply) to check whether PHP is supported or not. In the meantime, I would like to ensure that my code has no errors.

HTML:

```
<form action="message.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <p>Name <span class="requiredAsterisk">*</span></p>
        <input name="name"/>
        <p>Email <span class="requiredAsterisk">*</span></p>
        <input name="email"/>
        <p>Message <span class="requiredAsterisk">*</span></p>
        <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input class="sendMessage w3-large" type="submit" value="Send Message"/>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$header = 'From: ' .$_POST['name'] ."\r\n" .'Reply-to: ' .$_POST['email'] ."\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' .phpversion();
if (mail("email@mail.com", "Email from website", $_POST['message'], $header)) {
    echo ("<p>Email successfully sent</p>");
} else {
    echo ("<p>Email failed</p>");
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: When `mail` returns true, it just means that the email was accepted by the mail server. It doesn't mean that the email could be sent, was sent, or was delivered.

Comment: @fubar Does that mean this is a server-side issue?

Comment: Yes, I would say it's a server side issue. But that could be a configuration issue, blacklisting issue, anything. Hopefully your hosting company can provide some insight.

Comment: People should really stop upvoting duplicated questions...

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative to the original `mail()` function in PHP would be something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). As stated in the github page:

> the vast majority of code that you'll find online that uses the mail()
>   function directly is just plain wrong! Please don't be tempted to do
>   it yourself - if you don't use PHPMailer, there are many other
>   excellent libraries that you should look at before rolling your own -
>   try SwiftMailer, Zend_Mail, eZcomponents etc.

PHPMailer is super easy to set up and get going. This is the basic syntax to send an email:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net');     // Add a recipient

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: lol at "This is the basic syntax to send an email" :-) It's also completely useless if you don't have an SMTP at hand, as it will use the internal `mail()` function.

Comment: Sure, but he mentioned he had a hosting service so he most likely does have an SMTP at hand. Even if he didn't have a hosting service he could use countless other services that provide an SMTP services like Yahoo or Gmail. @Capsule

Comment: Yahoo or Gmail would block you as soon as the form is abused because of the traffic it would generate and shared hostings generally don't offer auth-SMTP. I'm not saying it's not a valid answer but I'm mitigating the enthusiasm :-)

Comment: True, they do have their down sides, but I'm just trying to help him out with an alternative in case he can't get it working with the `mail()` function.

Comment: Oh absolutely, but actually translating the OP's code into a `PHPMailer` syntax would look a bit less terrifying. For example, there's no multiple recipients, CC, BCC, attachment or alternate body as the message is dynamic. That's why I laughed at "This is the basic syntax to send an email". It's definitely not basic and might add a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

(I would probably comment this, but my rep is too low) You should use 
`$message = wordwrap($_POST['message'], 70, "\r\n");` so your message follows the documentation on [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). Besides this, your code seems to be fine. As you mentioned, it is probably related to your hosting provider, as it is common place for them to block the `mail` function. Also see [this question on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803994/php-mail-not-working-for-some-reason) for some extras which may the cause of your problem.