# Please help me in creating a submit form that gets submit and remains on the same page.

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I want to add submit form using php but also I want to stay on the same page after clicking the submit button. Also I want that the entries reset after submit button is clicked. I am new to php and I don't know anything about it so please help by giving me proper coding.

```js
This is the PHP code - 

<?php

if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
   // Prepare the email
$to = 'letsavepet@gmail.com';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail_from = $_POST['email'];
   $subject = 'Message sent from website';
   $message = $_POST['message'];

$header = "From: $name <$mail_from>";

   // Send it
   $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
   if($sent) {
   echo 'Your message has been sent successfully!';
   } else {
   echo 'Sorry, your message could not send.';
   }
}
?>
```

```html
<html><head><title>Contact Us</title>
</head><body>

<form method="post" action="contact.php" target="formDestination">
    <p>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required="required" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="6" cols="30" required="required"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send message" />
    </p>
</form>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Here's the thing... what you want to achieve is done using AJAX. So go learn AJAX... maybe with the Fetch API, which would be very useful. [More information over here...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) [and here...](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch)

Comment: Also, the idea behind StackOverflow isn't to do the work for you, but to solve issues regarding to a specific problem with some code you wrote and somehow isn't working. So try to do it on your own, maybe follow a tutorial, and if you're stuck on something (for example, you get an error), then ask another question about that. But try to research first, since the question may already have an answer.

Comment: How much research you should do before asking a question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/2960971

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `action` and `target` attributes of your `<form>` tag. A form tag without an `action` attribute defaults to submitting to the current page.

```js
<?php

if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
   // Prepare the email
$to = 'letsavepet@gmail.com';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail_from = $_POST['email'];
   $subject = 'Message sent from website';
   $message = $_POST['message'];

$header = "From: $name <$mail_from>";

   // Send it
   $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
   if($sent) {
   echo 'Your message has been sent successfully!';
   } else {
   echo 'Sorry, your message could not send.';
   }
}
?>
```

```html
<html><head><title>Contact Us</title>
</head><body>

<form method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required="required" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="6" cols="30" required="required"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send message" />
    </p>
</form>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Yes! Or an empty `target=""`, that would achieve the same result.

Comment: But tell me that if I will leave the action empty then how the form will know that what to do and which PHP is to be used.

Comment: @SuryanshManav By default modern browsers submit forms to the same url that served it up (if action is empty). You used to have to define the same url, but not so much these days.

Comment: @IncredibleHat thanks buddy!

Comment: Dont thank me, thank Ben, he gave you this answer :)

Comment: Ya I should thank him also. Thanks @Ben for your answer.

Comment: But Sadly this is not working as now I am not getting any message to my mail.

Comment: Did you combine your form.php with your contact.php ? Because the form is submitting to the form script, not contact.php. So whatever you have in contact.php should be merged into the top of the form script (whatever that's named).

Comment: That, and there are many, many things that can go wrong with PHP's `mail` function... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803994/php-mail-not-working-for-some-reason